# XmlSerializer and xsi:type

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I have following classes, note that `B` inherits `A`:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(B))]
public class A
{...}

public class B : A
{...}
```

When an instance of `B` is serialized, then the `xsi:type` attribute is added:

```
<A xsi:type="B">
```

Why does this happen? The result should be just `<B>`.

This is the code for serialization:

```
var b = new B();
using (var writer = new XmlTextWriterFull(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    var s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(B));
    s.Serialize(writer, b);
}
```

This doesn't happen with other classes that I serialize. Is it because the classes are in different namespaces?

How can I workaround this problem?

Comment: if you show the code how you serialize, poeople can help better.

Comment: how true, please see my edit

Comment: I don't know what `XmlTextWriterFull` is but this works `using (var writer = new StringWriter())
            {
                
                var s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(B));
                s.Serialize(writer, b);
                var xml = writer.ToString();
            }`

Comment: thanks, your solution works. My example is incomplete, and I made a serious thinking error. Sorry for the trouble, I will flag the question to be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
    B b = new B();
    byte[] data = SerializeObject(b);
    File.WriteAllBytes("test.xml", data);
```

Here is code for serialization

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Serialize object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    internal static byte[] SerializeObject(object data)
    {
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        //empty namespace...
        ns.Add("", "");
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(data.GetType());
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(memStream, data, ns);
        byte[] result = memStream.ToArray();
        memStream.Dispose();
        return result;
    }
```

And serialized result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<B>
</B>
```